# JavaScript in LiveCycle - Presence of Objects

Tags: javascript, livecycle

JavaScript Geniuses,

The desired result is for "recommend" and "authorization" to show if either of the two checkboxes are checked.

```
/*For Checkbox1: Fund1 */
if (this.rawValue == "1") {
  this.resolveNode("fund1").presence = "visible";
  this.resolveNode("recommend").presence = "visible";
  this.resolveNode("authorization").presence = "visible";
} else {
  this.resolveNode("fund1").presence = "hidden";
  this.resolveNode("recommend").presence = "hidden";
  this.resolveNode("authorization").presence = "hidden";
}

/*For Checkbox2 - Fund2: */
if (this.rawValue == "1") {
  this.resolveNode("fund2").presence = "visible";
  this.resolveNode("recommend").presence = "visible";
  this.resolveNode("authorization").presence = "visible";
} else {
  this.resolveNode("fund2").presence = "hidden";
  this.resolveNode("recommend").presence = "hidden";
  this.resolveNode("authorization").presence = "hidden";
}
```

If I check one checkbox, the required "recommend" and "authorization" objects are visible.  If I check both checkboxes then uncheck one, the "recommend" and "authorization" objects hide.  There are checkboxes for other funds that have a different approval requirement on the form.

What causes the issue?  What resolves it?  What is a cleaner way to write the code?  All guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Script Object to store all your util functions and give it a concrate name.
2. There you should create functions for making an object visible and invisible. This is not mandatory, but such structure will reduce the number of stupid mistakes (like missing some letters in the word "visible" and so on):

   ```
   function setVisible(field){
       if (field === null) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       }
       if (field === undefined) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       }
       if (field instanceof Array) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       }
       field.presence = "visible";
   }

   function setInvisible(field){
      if (field === null) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       }
       if (field === undefined) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       }
       if (field instanceof Array) {
           //do what ever you want with an error
       } 
       field.presence = "invisible";
   }
   ```
3. Create fucntions for setting needed states for authorization and recomended objects:

   ```
   function setStateAuth(){
     if(Page1.CheckBox1.rawValue == "1" || Page1.CheckBox2.rawValue == "1"){
       setVisible(Page1.Authorization);
     }else{
       setInvisible(Page1.Authorization);
     }
   }

   function setStateRec(){
     if(Page1.CheckBox1.rawValue == "1" || Page1.CheckBox2.rawValue == "1"){
       setVisible(Page1.Recommend);
     }else{
       setInvisible(Page1.Recommend);
     }
   }
   ```
4. In the click event of your CheckBox1 call methods for setting auth. and rec. state. And also set visibility for Fund1 object.

   ```
   Lib.setStateAuth();
   Lib.setStateRec();
      if(this.rawValue == "1"){
         Lib.setVisible(Fund1);
      }else{
         Lib.setInvisible(Fund1);
      }
   ```
5. In the click event of your CheckBox2 call methods for setting auth. and rec. state. And also set visibility for Fund2 object.

   ```
   Lib.setStateAuth();
   Lib.setStateRec();
     if(this.rawValue == "1"){
   Lib.setVisible(Fund2);
     }else{
   Lib.setInvisible(Fund2);
   }
   ```
6. Note, that working with objects using "resolveNode" method is not recommended (due to the performance issues). So, if you have a concrate, not dynamic number of pages, it is better to name then all and refer to them using their names. Like it is done in a sample, i've made

[Here you can get a sample PDF](https://yadi.sk/i/L171WEOj3FMFxR)